# CakePHP 3.x: how to write validation rule in controller?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I cannot figure out how to write a validation rule in my controller in CakePHP 3.0, But I could do this earlier in cakePHP 2.5.

My case: I have 2 fields `"care_call"` and `"number_of_calls"`; I want to write validation rule on `"number_of_calls"` when `"care_call"` field is checked.

How do I change the validation rule only for one action?

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of writing a new rule in the controller? Is it for conditional validation?

Comment: That problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: You want to change the validation rules in *one* action today, but what if your needs evolve ?